# Multiple Processes accessing the same file causes exception

Tags: c#, vba, file-io, exception

I wrote a Excel macro which writes excel data to a text file in every 3 seconds.

In the same time, I've a program written in C# language that accesses the same text file, produced by excel macro, and do some process then output to an xml file every 5 seconds.

The Problem I met is that, it sometimes causes an `IoException`, when the other  process is accessing the same txt file. The problem didn't occur frequently. Now I use a `try...catch` statement in the C# program and `On Error` statement in the excel macro to catch the exception to avoid stopping my program.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

> Exception:
>   System.IO.IOException: file used by another process

Comment: Which error you are getting while simultaneously accessing the file?

Comment: System.IO.IOException: file used by another process in C# program

Answer (score 0):

I think some another thread has already acquired the resource (file) that you are now trying to write, which results in IOException.

So in such scenario I would suggest that you should go with the lock synchronization while accessing the file.

Here is very good example that may help you "how to get file release and lock it for use?" - [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/164428/C-FileStream-Lock-How-to-wait-for-a-file-to-get-re)

Use this mechanism to lock file and wait for file to be release while attempting to write to file.

**Update**

Just a little more about referenced link.

> > It just iterate over while loop until it gets file open to write and then call the callback (Action) passing file instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your Excel Macro and your C# program might write to the same file at the same time.

You have two options here, either find a way to synchronize file writing between Excel and your application. Or you can use a Shadow Copy writer in your c# application (not sure if this can be achieved inside excel but one application using it should suffice provided that it always use VSS to write to the file)

You can check [AlphaVSS](http://alphavss.codeplex.com/) as a VSS handler for your application